# Imagens desalinhadas

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou usando o seguinte `.xml` como tela principal:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/gasolina"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ÁLCOOL X GASOLINA"
        android:onClick="iniciarTela1"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#7d7d7d" />

    <TextView
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/moedas"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="QUANTO VOU GASTAR?"
        android:onClick="iniciarTela2"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#7d7d7d" />


</TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/grafico"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="MÉDIA POR KM PERCORRIDO"
            android:onClick="iniciarTela3"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#7d7d7d" />

        <TextView
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/grafico2"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="MÉDIA POR KM INICIAL/FINAL"
            android:onClick="iniciarTela4"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#7d7d7d" />


    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AVALIAR APP"
        android:onClick="avaliar"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#122d98"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Ele fica assim na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é o seguinte as imagens da segunda coluna estão mais pra cima (não estão alinhadas) até fiz uma linha vermelha pra ficar mais nitido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado? como posso corrigir esse problema?

Comment: Primeira coisa que você deve fazer é conferir se realmente não existe espaço vazio na sua imagem png.

Comment: o tamanho das imagens são iguais

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro que você está comentendo é na propriedade `android:padding` do seu `TextView`.

Você está definindo `30dp` e `20dp`. Tente manter uniforme esse valor para ambos os `TextView`'s.

```
<TextView
    android:drawableTop="@mipmap/grafico2"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="MÉDIA POR KM INICIAL/FINAL"
    android:onClick="iniciarTela4"
    android:padding="20dp" <!-- altere esse valor para ambos TextView's -->
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#7d7d7d" />
```

Comment: nossa que erro bobo, não percebi que os padding estavam diferente obrigado.

Comment: @denis Normal! Porém, você gastou muito mais tempo criando uma pergunta aqui no SO do que procurando o verdadeiro erro! Não que isso seja uma coisa ruim, mas as vezes recorremos aos recursos antes mesmo de pensar um pouco, e nisso acabamos nos acomodando diante destas situações. São muitas as vezes que eu comecei fazer uma pergunta, e quando terminava ela, eu já tinha a solução e desistia de publicar. Abraços. Boa sorte.

Answer (score -1):

Ja tentou usar:

Ex:

```
layout_marginTop=
```

Ou

```
Layout_marginBotton=
```

Nas imagens